# Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class error after updrading Flutter SDK and Plugins

Tags: android, flutter, sdk, admob, flutter-dependencies

I am getting this error after upgrading Flutter SDK and plugins version and no idea how to solve...

If I remove the admob plugin I am not able to see the exception and it seems that it only shows up after the very first instalation either in an emulator or a real device.

I am completely stack in this issue, can anybody give a clue?

*Flutter SDK:*

Version 2.8.1

*Pubspec plugin versions:*

```
http: ^0.13.4
rect_getter: 1.1.0
admob_flutter: ^2.0.0
url_launcher: ^6.0.18
shimmer: ^2.0.0
flutter_native_splash: ^1.3.3
intl: ^0.17.0
firebase_messaging: ^11.2.5
firebase_core: ^1.11.0
flutter_holo_date_picker: ^1.0.1+2
email_validator: ^2.0.1
firebase_auth: ^3.3.5
purchases_flutter: ^3.9.2
device_info_plus: ^3.2.1
```

*Android/build.gradle:*

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

*App/build.gradle:*

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app.cryptoinvestment.defirocket"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 5
        versionName "2.0.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.0.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

*Error log:*

```
I/ment.defirocke(10314): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.google.android.ads.tasks.appdigest.a>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager$OnChecksumsReadyListener;
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClassNative(java.lang.String, java.lang.ClassLoader, java.lang.Object, dalvik.system.DexFile) (DexFile.java:-2)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(java.lang.String, java.lang.ClassLoader, java.lang.Object, dalvik.system.DexFile, java.util.List) (DexFile.java:283)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(java.lang.String, java.lang.ClassLoader, java.util.List) (DexFile.java:276)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.DexPathList$Element.findClass(java.lang.String, java.lang.ClassLoader, java.util.List) (DexPathList.java:738)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(java.lang.String, java.util.List) (DexPathList.java:493)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:141)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at java.lang.Class bf.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamiteloader@214815065@21.48.15 (100400-0):2)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at java.util.List agb.r(ahc, android.content.Context, bzj, com.google.ads.afma.g) (:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972:5)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at java.util.List agc.r(ahc, android.content.Context, bzj, com.google.ads.afma.g) (:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972:1)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at void agb.s(ahc, android.content.Context, bzj, com.google.ads.afma.g) (:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972:0)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at bzj agb.m(android.content.Context, com.google.ads.afma.g) (:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972:7)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at java.lang.String afw.r(android.content.Context, java.lang.String, int, android.view.View, android.app.Activity, byte[]) (:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972:8)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at java.lang.String afw.f(android.content.Context) (:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972:2)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at java.lang.String com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.i.g(android.content.Context, byte[]) (:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972:2)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at java.lang.String com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.i.f(android.content.Context) (:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972:0)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at java.lang.Object com.google.android.gms.ads.nonagon.load.i.call() (:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972:0)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at java.lang.Object bqs.a() (:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972:0)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at void bqb.run() (:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972:3)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at void bqt.run() (:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972:0)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at void java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at void java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at void java.lang.Thread.run() (Thread.java:764)
I/ment.defirocke(10314): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.content.pm.PackageManager$OnChecksumsReadyListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000030d/dl-AdsFdrDynamite.integ_214106404100000.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000030d/dl-AdsFdrDynamite.integ_214106404100000.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64]]
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:169)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:379)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at java.lang.Class bf.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamiteloader@214815065@21.48.15 (100400-0):3)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClassNative(java.lang.String, java.lang.ClassLoader, java.lang.Object, dalvik.system.DexFile) (DexFile.java:-2)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(java.lang.String, java.lang.ClassLoader, java.lang.Object, dalvik.system.DexFile, java.util.List) (DexFile.java:283)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(java.lang.String, java.lang.ClassLoader, java.util.List) (DexFile.java:276)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.DexPathList$Element.findClass(java.lang.String, java.lang.ClassLoader, java.util.List) (DexPathList.java:738)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(java.lang.String, java.util.List) (DexPathList.java:493)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:141)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at java.lang.Class bf.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamiteloader@214815065@21.48.15 (100400-0):2)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at java.util.List agb.r(ahc, android.content.Context, bzj, com.google.ads.afma.g) (:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972:5)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at java.util.List agc.r(ahc, android.content.Context, bzj, com.google.ads.afma.g) (:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972:1)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at void agb.s(ahc, android.content.Context, bzj, com.google.ads.afma.g) (:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972:0)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at bzj agb.m(android.content.Context, com.google.ads.afma.g) (:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972:7)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at java.lang.String afw.r(android.content.Context, java.lang.String, int, android.view.View, android.app.Activity, byte[]) (:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972:8)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at java.lang.String afw.f(android.content.Context) (:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972:2)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at java.lang.String com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.i.g(android.content.Context, byte[]) (:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972:2)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at java.lang.String com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.i.f(android.content.Context) (:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972:0)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at java.lang.Object com.google.android.gms.ads.nonagon.load.i.call() (:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972:0)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at java.lang.Object bqs.a() (:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972:0)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at void bqb.run() (:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972:3)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at void bqt.run() (:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972:0)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at void java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at void java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at void java.lang.Thread.run() (Thread.java:764)
I/ment.defirocke(10314): 
I/ment.defirocke(10314): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.google.android.ads.tasks.appdigest.a>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager$OnChecksumsReadyListener;
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClassNative(java.lang.String, java.lang.ClassLoader, java.lang.Object, dalvik.system.DexFile) (DexFile.java:-2)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(java.lang.String, java.lang.ClassLoader, java.lang.Object, dalvik.system.DexFile, java.util.List) (DexFile.java:283)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(java.lang.String, java.lang.ClassLoader, java.util.List) (DexFile.java:276)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.DexPathList$Element.findClass(java.lang.String, java.lang.ClassLoader, java.util.List) (DexPathList.java:738)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(java.lang.String, java.util.List) (DexPathList.java:493)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:141)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at java.lang.Class bf.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamiteloader@214815065@21.48.15 (100400-0):2)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at java.util.List agb.r(ahc, android.content.Context, bzj, com.google.ads.afma.g) (:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972:5)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at java.util.List agc.r(ahc, android.content.Context, bzj, com.google.ads.afma.g) (:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972:1)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at void agb.s(ahc, android.content.Context, bzj, com.google.ads.afma.g) (:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972:0)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at bzj agb.m(android.content.Context, com.google.ads.afma.g) (:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972:7)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at java.lang.String afw.r(android.content.Context, java.lang.String, int, android.view.View, android.app.Activity, byte[]) (:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972:8)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at java.lang.String afw.f(android.content.Context) (:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972:2)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at java.lang.String com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.i.g(android.content.Context, byte[]) (:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972:2)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at java.lang.String com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.i.f(android.content.Context) (:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972:0)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at java.lang.Object com.google.android.gms.ads.nonagon.load.i.call() (:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972:0)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at java.lang.Object bqs.a() (:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972:0)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at void bqb.run() (:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972:3)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at void bqt.run() (:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972:0)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at void java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at void java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at void java.lang.Thread.run() (Thread.java:764)
I/ment.defirocke(10314): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.content.pm.PackageManager$OnChecksumsReadyListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000030d/dl-AdsFdrDynamite.integ_214106404100000.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000030d/dl-AdsFdrDynamite.integ_214106404100000.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64]]
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:169)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:379)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at java.lang.Class bf.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamiteloader@214815065@21.48.15 (100400-0):3)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClassNative(java.lang.String, java.lang.ClassLoader, java.lang.Object, dalvik.system.DexFile) (DexFile.java:-2)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(java.lang.String, java.lang.ClassLoader, java.lang.Object, dalvik.system.DexFile, java.util.List) (DexFile.java:283)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(java.lang.String, java.lang.ClassLoader, java.util.List) (DexFile.java:276)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.DexPathList$Element.findClass(java.lang.String, java.lang.ClassLoader, java.util.List) (DexPathList.java:738)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(java.lang.String, java.util.List) (DexPathList.java:493)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:141)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at java.lang.Class bf.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamiteloader@214815065@21.48.15 (100400-0):2)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at java.util.List agb.r(ahc, android.content.Context, bzj, com.google.ads.afma.g) (:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972:5)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at java.util.List agc.r(ahc, android.content.Context, bzj, com.google.ads.afma.g) (:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972:1)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at void agb.s(ahc, android.content.Context, bzj, com.google.ads.afma.g) (:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972:0)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at bzj agb.m(android.content.Context, com.google.ads.afma.g) (:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972:7)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at java.lang.String afw.r(android.content.Context, java.lang.String, int, android.view.View, android.app.Activity, byte[]) (:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972:8)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at java.lang.String afw.f(android.content.Context) (:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972:2)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at java.lang.String com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.i.g(android.content.Context, byte[]) (:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972:2)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at java.lang.String com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.i.f(android.content.Context) (:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972:0)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at java.lang.Object com.google.android.gms.ads.nonagon.load.i.call() (:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972:0)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at java.lang.Object bqs.a() (:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972:0)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at void bqb.run() (:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972:3)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at void bqt.run() (:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972:0)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at void java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at void java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
I/ment.defirocke(10314):   at void java.lang.Thread.run() (Thread.java:764)
```

*Flutter doctor:*

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.1, on Microsoft Windows [VersiÃ³n 10.0.19043.1466], locale es-ES)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[√] Connected device (3 available)

• No issues found!
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Hi, did you ever solve this? Having the same problem